# Cubic Spline interpolation implementation

Tags: python, numpy

In the following code I am trying to implement the following

- write a function naturalSpline that implements cubic spline interpolation with natural boundary conditions
- Use a tridiagonal solver to solve the arising tridiagonal system for the first derivatives.
- The prototype of the function should read yy=naturalSpline(x,y,xx) where (x,y) are the input points and data, and xx are the points where the data should be interpolated.

I figured first I would start with the second bullet point, creating the tridiagonal solver. So this is just the Thomas algorithm. I spent some time to create this part of the code and I have formatted it below. But now I am trying to finish the first and third bullet points but I am not sure how to use what I have done already to finish those. Looking for some help with this! Thanks in advance.

```
import numpy as np
def TDMA(a,b,c,d):
    n = len(d)
    w= np.zeros(n-1,float)
    g= np.zeros(n, float)
    p = np.zeros(n,float)

    w[0] = c[0]/b[0]
    g[0] = d[0]/b[0]

    for i in range(1,n-1):
        w[i] = c[i]/(b[i] - a[i-1]*w[i-1])
    for i in range(1,n):
        g[i] = (d[i] - a[i-1]*g[i-1])/(b[i] - a[i-1]*w[i-1])
    p[n-1] = g[n-1]
    for i in range(n-1,0,-1):
        p[i-1] = g[i-1] - w[i-1]*p[i]
    return p
A = np.array([[10,2,0,0],[3,10,4,0],[0,1,7,5],   [0,0,3,4]],dtype=float)   
a = np.array([3.,1,3]) 
b = np.array([10.,10.,7.,4.])
c = np.array([2.,4.,5.])
d = np.array([3,4,5,6.])
print (TDMA(a, b, c, d))
```

Which gives the correct output, I even tested it against np.linalg.solve(a,b,c,d) to make sure it was correct

```
[ 0.14877589  0.75612053 -1.00188324  2.25141243]
```

Comment: It would be convenient to give some info on your setting, since some people may not know these formulas by heart. For example, is your polynomial p = a x^3 + ... + d or p = a + ... + d x^3 ? What is your specific problem? For spline interpolation, you solve the equations for (x,y) and get a number of polynomials that represent your spline. Now, for each point xx[i], you evaluate the polynomial that covers the range that the point in xx[i] lies in (the is exactly one k with xx[i] in [x_k, x_(k+1)] ).

Comment: @randomwalker it is f(x)=sinx on the interval [0,5pi] and the data y is given at 25 equally spaced points and should be interpolated to 250 equally spaced points , could you show how this is done? it would be greatly appreciated and I will accept your answer

Comment: In your code, what does A, a, b, c, and d stand for?

Comment: just the arrays in the triagdigonal system

Comment: I mean what do you expect them to be in your application of solving the spline equations, e.g. a=(x, f(x), f'(x))

Comment: I am not sure I thought solving the code I producedwould be a good first step but I don't think it has helped me

Answer (score 1):

For each interval [x_k, x_(k+1)], you can solve the four equations

1. p_k(x_k) = f(x_k) = y_k
2. p_k'(x_k) = f'(x_k) = d_k
3. p_k(x_(k+1)) = f(x_(k+1)) = y_(k+1)
4. p_k'(x_(k+1)) = f'(x_(k+1)) = d_(k+1)

(without checking your code, I assume that this is what you did).
From this, you can construct a dict

```
{'polynomials': [ [a_0, ..., d_0], ..., [a_24, ..., d_24] ],
 'knots': [x_0, ..., x_24]}
```

For each x of your 250 point, you check for which k the point x is in the interval [x_k, x_(k+1)] and evaluate p_k(x).

All of this is straight forward mathematics and python coding. If something is not clear, you are better of learning more about both fields, instead of getting specialized advise on this website.

Comment: As I said, this is seriously basic stuff. At this point, if you do not understand it deep enough to produce the code yourself, you have to learn more about python and/or spline interpolation. A good start is the wikipedia article on splines.